# How to find if point within a certain distance from latitude, longitude as MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql with places (latitude and longitude), given another point (P2) and a distance (D), I need to find through SQL query all places within that distance (D) from the other point (P2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it here :
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mysql query to get this information:

```
SELECT *, 
( 6373 * # Distance from center of earth to surface in     kilometers
acos(cos( radians( LATITUDE_OF_POINT) ) * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) * 
     cos(radians( `longitude` ) - radians( LONGITUDE_OF_POINT ) ) +
     sin(radians(LATITUDE_OF_POINT)) * sin(radians(`latitude`)) ) )
 `distance` 
 FROM 
     `YOUR_DB_TABLE` 
 HAVING 
     `distance` < YOUR_DESIRED_DISTANCE 
 ORDER BY 
     `distance`;
```